# Flutter movable and resizable widget handle position for four side

Tags: flutter

I tried to implement the movable and resizeable widget.. After googling and investigating integrated successfully. It has one additional needs. I need the resizeable handle for four sides instead on topcenter, bottom center, right center .... This is my code...

```
class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
              const TestWidget({
                Key? key,
              }) : super(key: key);

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return BlocBuilder(
              builder: (context, state) {
                return CustomizableBoxTransform();
              },
            );
          }
        }

        class CustomizableBoxTransform extends StatefulWidget {
          @override
          _CustomizableBoxTransformState createState() =>
              _CustomizableBoxTransformState();
        }

        class _CustomizableBoxTransformState extends State {
          double boxLeft = 50.0;
          double boxTop = 50.0;
          double boxWidth = 600;
          double boxHeight = 700.0;

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  left: boxLeft,
                  top: boxTop,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onPanUpdate: (details) {
                      setState(() {
                        boxLeft += details.delta.dx;
                        boxTop += details.delta.dy;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: boxWidth,
                      height: boxHeight,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "Drag me",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                for (HandlePosition position in HandlePosition.values)
                  if (position != HandlePosition.middleCenter)
                    Positioned(
                      left: getHandleLeft(position),
                      top: getHandleTop(position),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onPanUpdate: (details) {
                          setState(() {
                            if (position == HandlePosition.left) {
                              boxWidth -= details.delta.dx;
                              boxLeft += details.delta.dx;
                            } else if (position == HandlePosition.right) {
                              boxWidth += details.delta.dx;
                            } else if (position == HandlePosition.top) {
                              boxHeight -= details.delta.dy;
                              boxTop += details.delta.dy;
                            } else if (position == HandlePosition.bottom) {
                              boxHeight += details.delta.dy;
                            }
                          });
                        },
                        child: HandleWidget(),
                      ),
                    ),
              ],
            );
          }

          double? getHandleLeft(HandlePosition position) {
            switch (position) {
              case HandlePosition.left:
                return boxLeft - 5.0;
              case HandlePosition.right:
                return boxLeft + boxWidth - 5.0;
              case HandlePosition.top:
              case HandlePosition.bottom:
                return boxLeft + boxWidth / 2 - 5.0;
            }
          }

          double? getHandleTop(HandlePosition position) {
            switch (position) {
              case HandlePosition.top:
                return boxTop + 15.0;
              case HandlePosition.bottom:
                return boxTop + boxHeight - 5.0;
              case HandlePosition.left:
              case HandlePosition.right:
                return boxTop + boxHeight / 2 - 5.0;
            }
          }
        }

        enum HandlePosition {
          top,
          left,
          right,
          bottom,
          middleCenter,
        }

        class HandleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              width: 10.0,
              height: 5.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

**The result came like this
**
[image]

But my expectation is I need to resize the widget by clicking four sides of any area.. like this link.

https://box-transform-example.firebaseapp.com/

Flutter movable and resizable widget handle position for four side

Comment: why don't you just use this package? : `https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_box_transform`